# When I delete or clear contents of a cells getting a debug message

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code to capitalize most of my worksheet but when I delete or clear the contents I get the debug message.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:Z")) Is Nothing Then
Target.Value = UCase(Application.Substitute(Target.Value, " ", ""))
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What message do you get? What line does it occur on?

Comment: If you delete/change/add more than a single cell then Target is more than one cell and you cannot make the value uppercase as you are doing. Loop through the intersection of Target and columns A:Z and make each uppercase.

Comment: Does it happen outside of Z, because if so, then you are trying to substitute a deleted value.

Comment: `Target.Value` will be an array if `target.cells.count >1` so add a check for that, and check target still exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete/change/add more than a single cell then Target is more than one cell and you cannot make the value uppercase as you are doing. Loop through the intersection of Target and columns A:Z and make each uppercase.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:Z")) Is Nothing Then
        dim rng as range
        for each rng in Intersect(Target, Range("A:Z"))
            rng.Value = UCase(Replace(rng.Value, chr(32), vbnullstring))
        next rng
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```